# DirectXTK: Only SpriteBatch::Begin and Draw methods give LNK2019: unresolved external

Tags: directx11

I'm using DirectXTK Desktop 2017 with Visual Studio 2017 and SpriteBatch::Begin() and SpriteBatch::Draw() give an LNK2019 unresolved external error (but not SpriteBatch::End() or SpriteBatch::GetRotation()). Since I am able to call these functions as well as use WICTextureLoader to load a texture, I believe the include and library paths are all fine, but something might have gone wrong in the .lib compilation of the DirectXTK.

Anyone know what this might be due to? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and found it was due to having _XM_NO_INTRINSICS_ defined.  I also had to comment out the lines in DirectXMath.h that defined _XM_VECTORCALL_ so that XM_CALLCONV would be __fastcall.  I don't actually understand the underlying reason for this - just found it by trial and error...

Comment: If you are using ``_XM_NO_INTRINSICS_`` then you should rebuild the DirectXTK library to match. As to what's happenings, see [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxmath/pg-xnamath-internals#Call_Conventions)