# DirectXTK: SpriteBatch::Begin and Draw methods give LNK2019: unresolved external

Tags: directx, directx11, spritebatch, spritefont

Right now, im using DirectXTK (version 2020.2.24.4) and Visual Studio 2019.

My declarations look like this:

```
    std::unique_ptr<SpriteFont> m_font;
    std::unique_ptr<SpriteBatch> m_spriteBatch;
```

and my code look like this:

```
    m_font = std::make_unique<SpriteFont>(m_device.Get(), L"myfile.spritefont");
    m_spriteBatch = std::make_unique<SpriteBatch>(m_deviceContext.Get());

    m_fontPos.x = 1080 / 2.f;
    m_fontPos.y = 720 / 2.f;

    const wchar_t* output = L"Hello World";
    DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector2 origin = m_font->MeasureString(output) / 2.f;

    m_spriteBatch.get()->Begin();
    m_font.get()->DrawString(m_spriteBatch.get(), output, m_fontPos);
    m_spriteBatch.get()->End();
```

The functions `SpriteBatch::Begin()`, `SpriteBatch::Draw()` and `SpriteFont::MeasureString()` give me a LNK2019 error.

I found this thread [DirectXTK: Only SpriteBatch::Begin and Draw methods give LNK2019: unresolved external](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/174148/directxtk-only-spritebatchbegin-and-draw-methods-give-lnk2019-unresolved-ext). But the answer didnt solve my errors

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your linker setup properly?

Comment: How do i check that?

Comment: In the linker settings of VS most likely.

Comment: Are you use NuGet packages or did did use project-to-project references?  See [DirectXTK wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DirectXTK)

Comment: Based on the version, I'm guessing it's NuGet. Make sure the NuGet package is added to your EXE project if you have multiple projects in your solution.

Comment: I've started using [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) to manage my external deps and DirectXTK is already included as a port.  You need to be using a CMake workflow however...